# got an error with rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Hi everybody  got some trouble with the rails console .
here is the error.

```
>> Page.editors << me
NoMethodError: undefined method `editors' for #<Class:0x1038560e8>
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):5
```

here is the relation between the models.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :permalink, :position
  has_and_belongs_to_many :editors, :class_name => "AdminUser"
  #has_and_belongs_to_many :AdminUser
  belongs_to :subject
  has_many :sections
end
```

the second one

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :username
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
  scope :named, lambda{|first,last| where(:first_name => first,:last_name => last)}
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong...it should be

```
p = Page.first

p.editors << me
```

The editors is an instance method which is made automatically through the associations..refer to the Rails Guide for more information...

Answer (score 1):

`editors` is an **instance** method on `Page`, *not* a class method of `Page`. You need to instantiate a new instance of `Page` to call `editors` on it.

```
page = Page.find(...)
page.editors << me
```

What you're trying to do is append `me` by using `<<` on the `Page` **class** which doesn't make sense since you're not specifying **which** `Page` to append `me` to.

Some reading:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: or `Page.new.editors`, though that can be pretty worthless as you'd lose the ability to refer to the new `Page` instance you just created. That said I do use `[Some class].new.[some_method]` fairly often, like when I want to play around with an instance method; I find it quicker than assigning it to a variable and then calling that variable.

Comment: Agreed. I changed my example to use `find` instead since it's a much more likely *(and useful)* scenario.